# При установке ARCH LINUX не видит второй диск

Tags: linux, archlinux

Хочу установить arch linux второй системой, но(!), когда ты прописываешь cfdisk, он находит только тот диск, на котором установлена винда(С). Больше никаких не видит, главное, с граф.установкой с помощью других дистрибутивов linux, всё находится, а такая проблема ток с арчем.

Comment: Какой именно? Я просто не особо шарю за новые дистрибутивы и т.д.

Comment: `cfdisk`' у диск задаётся в аргументах, сам он ничего не находит... введи `cfdisk /dev/sdb` и будет радость...